# Is there a way to tell what columns an SQLite internal index is on?

Tags: sqlite

```
sqlite> create table foo(x TEXT PRIMARY KEY, y TEXT UNIQUE);
sqlite> select * from sqlite_master;
table|foo|foo|2|CREATE TABLE foo(x TEXT PRIMARY KEY, y TEXT UNIQUE)
index|sqlite_autoindex_foo_1|foo|3|
index|sqlite_autoindex_foo_2|foo|4|
```

For user-defined indices, the last column of `sqlite_master` tells me what columns they are on. But as you can see, for the indices implicitly created by (non-rowid) `PRIMARY KEY` and `UNIQUE`, this information is absent. Is there a reliable way for me to tell which `autoindex` is which?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no difference between internal and explicitly-created indexes; you can get information about them with the same PRAGMAs ([index_list](http://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_index_list), [index_info](http://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_index_info), [index_xinfo](http://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_index_xinfo)):

```
sqlite> pragma index_list(foo);
seq         name                    unique      origin      partial
----------  ----------------------  ----------  ----------  ----------
0           sqlite_autoindex_foo_2  1           u           0
1           sqlite_autoindex_foo_1  1           pk          0
sqlite> pragma index_xinfo(sqlite_autoindex_foo_1);
seqno       cid         name        desc        coll        key
----------  ----------  ----------  ----------  ----------  ----------
0           0           x           0           BINARY      1
1           -1                      0           BINARY      0
sqlite> pragma index_xinfo(sqlite_autoindex_foo_2);
seqno       cid         name        desc        coll        key
----------  ----------  ----------  ----------  ----------  ----------
0           1           y           0           BINARY      1
1           -1                      0           BINARY      0
```